# ¿Cómo usar AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Tengo esta clase la cual extiende de **AsyncTask**:

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {


    protected void onPostExecute(String a) {
        //process message
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        try
        {
            //Se define el objeto URL
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            //Se arma y configura un objeto de conexión HttpURLConnection
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            //Recibimos la respuesta de la petición en formato InputStream
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("This is the length >>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ connection.getContentLength());
            //Decodificamos el InputStream a un objeto BitMap
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }
}
```

En otra clase tengo el siguiente código el cuál usa el `Bitmap` de `doInBackGround()`.

```
DownloadImage di=new DownloadImage();
                  di.execute("http://192.168.150.101:8080/TDIDP/imagenes/IMG-20173175029");
                  final Bitmap bitmap =di.doInBackground();
```

Pero tengo el siguientes errores:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>      04-20 18:03:08.520 23442-23442/com.example.friky.tdidp W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.friky.tdidp.DownloadImage.doInBackground(DownloadImage.java:30)
>       04-20 18:03:08.520 23442-23442/com.example.friky.tdidp W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.friky.tdidp.MainMenuUsuario.cargarDatos(MainMenuUsuario.java:113)

¿Cómo puedo obtener de forma correcta el Bitmap que está en doInBackGround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El `Asynctask` esta definido con estos parámetros:

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {
```

por lo tanto onPostExecute() debería ser:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //process image!
    }
```

ya que debería recibir un `bitmap` no un `String`.

---

#### Como descargar una imagen mediante un Asynctask.

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

 @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap !=null){
            //Realiza operación con el Bitmap descargado.
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

el cual llamarias de esta forma:

```
DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
downloadImage.execute("http://www.mydomain.com/myimage");
```

---

Métodos de la clase AsyncTask

> - [onPreExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute()): Se ejecuta antes de iniciar el proceso en el mismo hilo de ejecución que la aplicación. Este método se utiliza normalmente para configurar la tarea, por ejemplo mostrando una barra de progreso en la interfaz de usuario.
> - [doInBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)): Ejecuta la tarea en un hilo diferente al de ejecución con el fin de no bloquear la UI. Este método es necesario
>     sobrescribirlo.
> - [onProgressUpdate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)):  Este método recibe información sobre el progreso de la tarea llamando a la función `publishProgress()` desde
>     `doInBackground()`. Se ejecuta en el hilo principal y comunmente se
>     utiliza para actualizar elementos que informen del progreso de la
>     tarea en el AsyncTask.
> - [onPostExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)): Este método es llamado al finalizar el método `doInBackground()` y recibe el resultado para tratarlo y actualizar la
>     interfaz de usuario en consecuencia. Se define como el punto final de
>     la ejecución de un AsyncTask.

Comment: Eso  quiere decir que después del doInBackground se ejecuta el onPostExecute?

Comment: Exactamente @FrEqDe , onPostExecute() es el punto final de la ejecución de un AsyncTask.

Comment: Ahora entiendo por que lo que uno retorna es lo que el otro recibe cómo parámetro.

Comment: Exactamente!, agregué información sobre los métodos del AsyncTask.

Comment: Gracias, así se entiende mejor.