# Alternativa para no tener que crear la conexión cada vez que quiera realizar una operación en la base de datos MYSQL con una App de Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, base-de-datos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de android que se conecta a una base de datos de mysql alojada en azure. El asunto es que cada vez que quiero insertar o actualizar registros tengo que crear una nueva conexión a la base de datos, la cual dura sus segundos, pocos pero para al cliente final lo mejor es que la app sea totalmente fluida. Estoy utilizando la librería mysql-connector-java-5.1.47 para poder crear la conexión con la base de datos.

Entonces era para ver si existe alguna manera o alternativa para no tener que estar creando una nueva conexión por cada operación que se tenga que hacer (ya que son muy frecuentes).

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Ésta es la clase que realiza la conexión:

```
    public class CreateConnectionWithDatabase {

    public CreateConnectionWithDatabase(){

    }

    public Connection createConnection(String user, String password, String database, String server) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); //politica de connexion

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Connection connection = null;

        String connectionUrl = null;

        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();

        connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+"/"+database;

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionUrl, user, password);

        return connection;

    }



}
```

Y cuando tengo que realizar alguna operación ya tiene que haber una conexión, la cual la hago con ésta linea de código:

```
createConnectionWithDatabase = new CreateConnectionWithDatabase();
        connection = createConnectionWithDatabase.createConnection("jxxxu@lxxza-sxxxer","12xxxa", "gym_cachi","xxxxx-server.xxxx.xxxxx.azure.com:3306");
```

Comment: Deberías de poner tu archivo de conexión dentro de alguna carpeta, y cuando la ocupes en algún otro archivo, solo hagas el import de la misma, así no tendrás que escribir las lineas de código siempre que las ocupes.

Comment: Si estás haciendo una app como para google play, es una muy mala idea conectarte de esta forma a la base de datos. No me alcanza este espacio para explicar todos los motivos pero son varios. La conexión a la bd debería estar en un servidor / hosting (php, java, etc), y la app hablar con ese servidor.

Comment: @Juan tu comentario me llamó muchisímo la atención, no tiene alguna página en donde expliquen más al respecto? Y muchas gracias por cierto

Comment: Está en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827263/2225960

Comment: usa un servicio RESTful

Answer (score 3):

En este caso, no es recomendable que la aplicación realice la conexión a la base de datos una y otra vez,  cada vez que realices una operación.

Te recomiendo estas opciones:

> - Abrir y mantener la conexión a la base de datos durante la sesión de tu aplicación. En este caso debes validar si la conexión existe de otra forma volver a abrirla.
> - Descargar la base de datos y realizar las consultas directamente en la base de datos descargada en disco, esto puede ser posible si la
>     base de datos no tiene un tamaño considerable.
> - Usar un Web Service, en este caso expondrás los métodos que realizan la consulta y el servicio realizaría la conexión a la base de datos.

Te sugiero revisar el siguiente tutorial:

[AGREGAR UN WEB SERVICE A UN PROYECTO AZURE](https://nicolocodev.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/windows-azure-agregar-un-web-service-a-un-proyecto-azure/)

---

No es recomendable tampoco agregar la politica para permitir tareas en el hilo principal:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); //politica de connexion
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

para esto puedes usar un AsyncTask:

[¿Cómo usar AsyncTask?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64368/c%C3%B3mo-usar-asynctask)